# Why does the shell script give command not found error?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am new to shell script. I create the below script to count the total lines of files in directory.

It looks simple. line 7 is giving the correct number for the file.

```
#!/bin/bash
  
totalCount=0;
count=0;

for f in "$1"/*
do
  echo $(grep -o 'timestamp' "$f" | wc -l);        #line 7
  count = $(grep -o 'timestamp' "$f" | wc -l);     #line 8
  totalCount = totalCount + count;                 #line 9
done

echo $totalCount
```

however, line 8 and 9 keep giving below errors.

```
./myscript.sh: line 9: count: command not found
./myscript.sh: line 10: totalCount: command not found
```

I tried to change 'count' to '$count', still does not work.

What am i missing here?

Comment: Assignments shouldn't have spaces around the `=`.

Comment: Also, `totalCount=...` is missing a `$()` around the `...`. Try https://www.shellcheck.net/; it finds errors like these, explains them, and suggests fixes.

Comment: Check https://www.shellcheck.net/ for common shell errors like the one mentioned above.